# c# use reflection to get a private member variable from a derived class

Tags: c#, reflection, inheritance

I have the following structure:

```
abstract class Parent {}


class Child : Parent
{   
    // Member Variable that I want access to:
    OleDbCommand[] _commandCollection;

    // Auto-generated code here
}
```

Is it possible to use reflection from within the Parent class to access the _commandCollection within the Child class? If not any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

**EDIT:**
Its probably worth mentioning that in the abstract Parent class I plan to use IDbCommand[] to handle the _commandCollection object as not all my TableAdapters will be using OleDb to connect to their respective databases.

**EDIT2:**
For all the comments saying ... just add a property of function to the child class, I can't as its automatically generated by the VS Designer. I really don't want to have to re-do my work every time I change something in the designer!

Comment: wow. that's a BIG code smell. why not put the `_commandCollection` in the parent, and type it as `IDbCommand[]`? then you have what you want, you just cast up in the child class.

Comment: @TK I would suggest you to check out your code architecture. This situation happens if there is a missing controller class.

Comment: TK - I can relate to your problem.  MS has a habit of setting private, things in generated code that really need to be accessed from derived classes.  I'm going to be using this for something similar.

Comment: As an example of needing a solution for non-owned classes, Microsoft's [System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.ValidationAttribute](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations/DataAnnotations/ValidationAttribute.cs,78e76a9eac947a00) has many private members that should have been available for extension. There is a real and practical need to access "private" things when the design is broken.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
// _commandCollection is an instance, private member
BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic;

// Retrieve a FieldInfo instance corresponding to the field
FieldInfo field = GetType().GetField("_commandCollection", flags);

// Retrieve the value of the field, and cast as necessary
IDbCommand[] cc =(IDbCommand[])field.GetValue(this);
```

Array covariance should ensure that the cast is successful.

I assume some designer will be generating the subclasses? Otherwise, a protected property is probably what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible, though it's a decidedly bad idea.

```
    var field = GetType().GetField("_commandCollection", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

---

I think what you really want to do is provide a method for the child classes to provide the parent with the required data:

```
protected abstract IEnumerable<IDBCommand> GetCommands();
```

Comment: I realise that in most cases private really means 'hands off don't touch', but in this case I'm trying to have a single solution to allow all my (100+) Table Adapters to use this generic piece of code rather than creating and maintaining 100+ partial classes.